# Not clear about how to organize Python code with multiple functions as separate files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently wrote a Python code with about 200 lines. The code has several functions, which are called in the `def main()`. I structured it for simplicity, but I think I could do better by saving some of the functions in a separate `.py` file. So the structure would look like this:

```
filename: funcs_set1.py 

def func1():
    # does something 1

def func2():
    # does something 2
```

another file:

```
filename: funcs_set2.py 

def func_a(x,y):
    # does something A

def func_b(z):
    # does something B
```

Now, in the main driver file:

```
import funcs_set1
import funcs_set2
def main():
    x = funcs_set1.func2()
    y = funcs_set1.func1()
    z = funcs_set2.func_a(x,y)
    answer = funcs_set2.func_b(z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a better layout/structure than this?
The reason I want to keep functions in separate files is because I think that such structure will be useful at the time of debugging and identifying errors when improving this code. 
What I HATE is having to import multiple .py files. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is just my idea I am not sure. One thing when creating multiple different files is circular imports. This is where you import a file into main.py, and you will receive an error if you try and import main.py into the second file.

My solution:
Create main.py that will be the file that initiates the program, and keep the main stuff in main(what a concept) and have small things in other files.

What I have done:
I currently have three files. I have a main.py which runs a very important GUI with 800 lines of code. I have another called texting_gui which had 600 lines and an information.py another GUI.

I had the same issue but I learned to live with the large files. Plus it looks cool when you scroll through huge files :). Have large files with lots of code in them, but have crucial parts that will need a lot of space by themselves as long as you do not try and circular import

Note: I am only 16 and have self taught with no formal training so this is all based off my own opinion. Sorry for such a long answer and I hope it helps you out.